Gmail integration with Salesforce as a bulk update this for multiple users at once?
Setting up Gmail (G Suite) integration with Salesforce (extension) for one user is a straightforward process, but how can we efficiently bulk update this for an entire profile or multiple users at once? What permissions or configurations are necessary for this kind of setup?
Enable Gmail and Salesforce integration for multiple users simultaneously to streamline the creation of Salesforce records from Gmail. Simplify the setup process for existing integrations and ensure efficient use across teams
